# Best way to retrieve 150,000 records from Oracle with JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have been searching for an answer to this today, and it seems the best approach divides opinion somewhat.

I have 150,000 records that I need to retrieve from an Oracle database using JDBC. Is it better to retrieve the data using one `select` query and allowing the JDBC driver to take care of transferring the records from the database using Oracle cursor and default `fetchSize` - OR to split up the query into batches using `LIMIT / OFFSET`?

With the `LIMIT / OFFSET` option, I think the pros are that you can take control over the number of results you return in each chunk. The cons are that the query is executed multiple times, and you also need to run a `COUNT(*)` up front using the same query to calculate the number of iterations required.

The pros of retrieving all at once are that you rely on the JDBC driver to manage the retrieval of data from the database. The cons are that the `setFetchSize()` hint can sometimes be ignored meaning that we could end up with a huge `resultSet` containing all 150,000 records at once!!

Would be great to hear some real life experiences solving similar issues, and recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a one-time operation? 150k records with 500 bytes per record is actually not that much with modern hardware where you usually have GBs of memory available. It should just work with a simple select. Using `LIMIT` will make the querying more complex as you need to take care of paging the results and also the DB needs to sort the data wih each query.

Comment: This operation would happen once or more every day.

Answer (score 0):

The native way in Oracle JDBC is to use the `prepareStatement` for the query, `executeQuery` and fetch 
in a loop the results with defined `fetchSize`

Yes, of course the details are Oracle Database and JDBC Driver Version dependent and in some case the required  `fetchSize`
can be ignored. But the typical problem is that the required fetch size is reset to  `fetchSize = 1` and you effectively makes a round trip for each record. (not that you get all records at once).

Your alternative with `LIMIT` seems to be meaningfull on the first view. But if you investigate the implementation you will *probably decide to not use it*.

Say you will divide the result set in 15 chunks 10K each:

You open 15 queries, each of them on average with a half of the resource consumption as the original query (`OFFSET` select the data and skips them).
So the only think you will reach is that the processing will take aproximatly 7,5x more time.

**Best Practice**

Take your query, write a simple script with JDBC fetch, use 10046 trace to see the effective used fetch size.
Test with a range of fetch sizes and observe the perfomance; choose the optimal one.

Comment: In other words the pagination with `OFFSET` is not suitable if the intention is to read all rows. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684094/oracle-pagination-strategy?answertab=oldest#comment84441292_48712555)

Answer (score -1):

my preference is to maintain a safe execution time with the ability to continue if interrupted.  i prefer this approach because it is future proof and respects memory and execution time limits.  remember you're not planning for today, you're planning for 6m down the road.  what may be 150,000 today may be 1.5m in 6 months.

i use a length + 1 recipe to know if there is more to fetch, although the count query will enable you to do a progress bar in % if that is important.

when considering  150,000 record result set, this is a memory pressure question.    this will depend on the average size of each row.  if it is a row with three integers, that's small.  if it is a row with a bunch of text elements to store user profile details then that's potentially very large.  so be prudent with what fields you're pulling.

also need to ask - you may not need to pull all the records all the time.  it may be useful to apply a sync pattern.  to only pull records with an updated date newer than your last pull.

Comment: The records will be varchar fields and a numeric primary key. Averaging around 500 bytes per record. All records will be processed with each run

Comment: seems reasonable - is it a static limit of 150,000 or will that grow over time?

Comment: Could easily grow as this is product data