# Oracle Pagination strategy

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination, oracle12c

I want to fetch million of rows from a table between two timestamps and then do processing over it. Firing a single query and retrieving all the records at once looks to be a bad strategy as it might exceed the memory capabilities of my JVM program.

I have read this article:

http://oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sql/indexes/top-n-pagination.html

Hence, I am planning to do pagination in batches of 1000 and have come up with following strategy:
Let's say `Start_Date = X and End_Date = Y`

1. Fire a query,

`select * from table where CREATE_TIMESTAMP > X AND CREATE_TIMESTAMP < Y ORDER BY CREATE_TIMESTAMP FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY.`

2. If I get less than 1000 rows only, that means all records have been completed. If I get exactly 1000 rows, that means, there might be more records.
3. `set X = CREATE_TIMESTAMP of 1000th record`

   `select * from table where CREATE_TIMESTAMP > X AND CREATE_TIMESTAMP < Y ORDER BY CREATE_TIMESTAMP FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY`

This repeats until I get less than 1000 records.

Does anyone see any issues with this approach?

Comment: Mentioned article refers to Oracle 12

Comment: Updated .. Its oracle 12 only...

Comment: What happens if you have multiple records with timestamp X?

Comment: Yeah thats one case ... If I make sure my processing is idempotent, it should not be a problem . .. right?

Comment: Well, you might skip some rows. If row 1001 has the same timestamp as row 1000, it won't get picked up by the second query. I'd suggest adding a unique key to your sort, for example `ORDER BY CREATE_TIMESTAMP, ROWID`, `set Z = ROWID of 1000th record`, and then do `WHERE CREATE_TIMESTAMP >= X AND ROWID > Z`

Comment: What sort of processing do you want to do on the data. The most efficient, most performative way of manipulating data is the database, with SQL, or PL/SQL. Oracle has such a rich array of functionality -  mathematical, analytical, text-based, etc - that there really isn't much it can't do.

Comment: You don't need to fetch all rows to memory - retrieve only one record at a time from the resultset, then process that record, then fetch next one and so one and so one. The resultset (for example in java) automatically prefetches records in batches, one batch (several dozen record) with each database round trip, there is no need for pagination at all.

Comment: I have to totally concur with @APC here. You will likely be orders of magnitude faster by moving the processing to the data, rather than data to the processing. Moreover, once you adopt this strategy, you have the ability to use things like parallelism etc.  People often (incorrectly) do not think of the database as a data processing engine.

Comment: I want to publish the records to Kafka topic .. @APC

Comment: @krokodilko I had tried this approach. I believe you are mentioning setting "fetch size" which will only fetch n records at a time, and will maintain a forward only cursor. Right? I am not sure why this approach would be better one. I feel stateless should be better than stateful.

Comment: You are right @kfinity , how about if I add CREATE_TIMESTAMP >=X AND CREATE_TIMESTAMP <= Y. This might fetch repeated records, but should be fine If I ensure idempotency .. right?

Comment: You may check other approaches to publish Oracle data to Kafka. Some of them use [redo log mining](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1E3ejjp-wYQJ:blog.dbvisit.com/streaming-oracle-database-change-data-to-kafka-hello-dbvisit-replicate-connector-for-kafka-part-4/+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=at&client=firefox-b), other [read incemental on IDs](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11524.streaming-oracle-database-table-data-to-apache-kafka), but non of them (I found) use pagination.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I do not have to stream the changes of database to Kafka. Its on the request basis on timestamp.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja Well, for a small number of records per second any approach will be suitable. To scale, I'd recommend to try some simple mechanism to parallelize the DB readers (**do not** select *for update* and mark record as closed, as this will not scale) and a possibility to pass the messages to Kafka in a *batch*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pagination pattern](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/split-the-contents-of-a-website-with-the-pagination-design-pattern) has been invented for the purpose of websites presentation (in opposite to scrolling navigation), and works best there. In short, the live user is practically unable to view thousands/millions of records at once, so the information is divided into short pages (50~200 records), where one query is usually sent to the database for each page. The user usually clicks on a few pages only, but does not browse all of them, in addition the user needs a bit of time to browse the page, so the queries are not sent to the database one by one, but in long intervals. The time to retrieve a chunk of data is much shorter than retrieving all millions of record, so the user is happy because he does not have to wait long for subsequent pages, and the overall system load is smaller.

---

But it seems from the question that the nature of your application is oriented to **batch processing** rather than to the **web presentation**. The application must fetch all records and do some operations/transformations (calculations) on each of the records. In this case , completely different design patterns are used (stream/pipelined processing, sequence of steps, parallel steps/operations etc), and pagination will not work, if you go that way **you will kill your system performance.**

---

**Instead of fancy theory, let's look at simple and practical example which will show you what differences in speed we are talking here**
Let say there is a table `PAGINATION` with about 7 millions of records:

```
create table pagination as
select sysdate - 200 * dbms_random.value As my_date, t.*
from (
    select o.* from all_objects o 
    cross join (select * from dual connect by level <= 100)
    fetch first 10000000 rows only
) t;

select count(*) from pagination;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   7369600
```

---

Let say there is an index created on `MY_DATE` column, and index statistics are fresh:

```
create index PAGINATION_IX on pagination( my_date );

BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( 'TEST', 'PAGINATION', method_opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS' ); END;
/
```

Let say that we are going to process about 10% of records from the table between the below dates:

```
select count(*) from pagination
where my_date between date '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-21';

  COUNT(*)
----------
    736341
```

---

and finally let say that our "processing" for simplicity, will consist in simple summing of lengths of one of field. 
This is a simple paging implementation:

```
public class Pagination {

    public static class RecordPojo {
        Date myDate;
        String objectName;

        public Date getMyDate() {
            return myDate;
        }
        public RecordPojo setMyDate(Date myDate) {
            this.myDate = myDate;
            return this;
        }
        public String getObjectName() {
            return objectName;
        }
        public RecordPojo setObjectName(String objectName) {
            this.objectName = objectName;
            return this;
        }
    };

    static class MyPaginator{

        private Connection conn;
        private int pageSize;
        private int currentPage = 0;

        public MyPaginator( Connection conn, int pageSize ) {
            this.conn = conn;
            this.pageSize = pageSize;
        }

        static final String QUERY = ""
                + "SELECT my_date, object_name FROM pagination "
                + "WHERE my_date between date '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-21' "
                + "ORDER BY my_date "
                + "OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY";

        List<RecordPojo> getNextPage() {
            List<RecordPojo> list = new ArrayList<>();
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try( PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);) {
                ps.setInt(1, pageSize * currentPage++ );
                ps.setInt(2,  pageSize);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while( rs.next()) {
                    list.add( new RecordPojo().setMyDate(rs.getDate(1)).setObjectName(rs.getString(2)));
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try{rs.close();}catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            return list;
        }

        public int getCurrentPage() {
            return currentPage;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String ...x) throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
        ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:test/test@//localhost:1521/orcl");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long value = 0;
        int pageSize = 1000;

        try( Connection conn = ds.getConnection();){
            MyPaginator p = new MyPaginator(conn, pageSize);
            List<RecordPojo> list;
            while( ( list = p.getNextPage()).size() > 0 ) {
                value += list.stream().map( y -> y.getObjectName().length()).mapToLong(Integer::longValue).sum();
                System.out.println("Page: " + p.getCurrentPage());
            }
            System.out.format("==================\nValue = %d, Pages = %d,  time = %d seconds", value, p.getCurrentPage(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000);
        }
    }
}
```

---

A result is:

```
Value = 18312338, Pages = 738,  time = 2216 seconds
```

---

Now let's test a very simple stream based solution - just take only one record, process it, discard it (freeing up memory), and take the next one.

```
public class NoPagination {

    static final String QUERY = ""
            + "SELECT my_date, object_name FROM pagination "
            + "WHERE my_date between date '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-21' "
            + "ORDER BY my_date ";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
        ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:test/test@//localhost:1521/orcl");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long count = 0;

        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try( Connection conn = ds.getConnection();){
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while( rs.next()) {
                // processing
                RecordPojo r = new RecordPojo().setMyDate(rs.getDate(1)).setObjectName(rs.getString(2)); 
                count+=r.getObjectName().length();
            }
            System.out.format("==================\nValue = %d, time = %d seconds", count, (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000);
        }finally {
            try { rs.close();}catch(Exception e) {}
            try { ps.close();}catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }
```

---

A result is:

```
Value = 18312328, time = 11 seconds
```

Yes - 2216 seconds / 11 seconds = 201 times faster - **20 100 % faster !!!**
Unbelievable ? You can test it yourself.
This example shows how important it is to choose the right solution (right design patterns) to solve the problem.

Comment: The theory predicts the pagination should make 350x more index read access, as  the first query reads the first 1K rows, but the last query all 700K rows and skips the first 699K rows. The DB cache mechanisms makes the increase of the elapsed time not so dramatic. Nice illustration of the *inappropriate use of pagination pattern if the intention is to process all rows'.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say if you were planning on adjusting "X" and "Y" each time you do the pagination.  If you don't then approach is probably only valid if you have a high confidence that the data is fairly static.

Consider the following example:

My table T has 100 rows date timestamp for "today", with ID=1 to 100 respectively, and I want the last 20 rows for my first page. So I do this:

```
select * 
from T 
where date_col = trunc(sysdate) 
order by id desc
fetch first 20 rows only
```

I run my query and get ID=100 down to 80.  So far so good - it is all on the user's page, and they take 30 seconds mins to read the data.  During that time, another 17 records have been added to the table (ID=101 to 117).

Now the user presses "Next Page"

Now I run the query again to get the next set

```
select * 
from T 
where date_col = trunc(sysdate) 
order by id desc
offset 20 fetch next 20 rows only
```

They will not see rows 80 down to 60, which would be their expectation, becuase the data has changed.  They would

a) get rows ID=117 down to 97, and skip them due to the OFFSET
b) then get rows ID=97 down to 77 to be displayed on screen

They'll be confused because they are seeing pretty much the same set of rows as they did on the first page.

For pagination against changing data, you generally want to stay away from the offset clause, and use your application to take note of where you got up to, ie

Page 1

```
select * 
from T 
where date_col = trunc(sysdate) 
order by id desc
fetch first 20 rows only
```

I fetch ID=100 down to 80...I *take note* of the 80.  My next query will then be

```
select * 
from T 
where date_col = trunc(sysdate) 
AND ID<80
order by id desc
fetch first 20 rows only
```

and my next query would be

```
select * 
from T 
where date_col = trunc(sysdate) 
AND ID<60
order by id desc
fetch first 20 rows only
```

and so forth.